# Special character in url like (å æ ø) results in a 404 error Facelets?

Tags: url, seo, special-characters, facelets

I am unable to navigate to a page that it is correctly configured in the facelets config file as follows:

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>nyhet</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/Bughaugane-område-Nyheiter.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Clicking on an anchor that references url causes a 404 error:

```
<li><a jsfc="h:link" outcome="nyhet">#{global.nyhet}</a></li>
```

A similar issue is experienced with usage of special chars in file names. 
Is this a Facelets or just an HTML issue?
How can I fix this ( I know the chars are to blame, because removing them resolves the issue).

I need to keep the words with weird chars for SEO.

Comment: Apparently the issue can only be resolved by removing special chars as question is being voted to be closed and apparently it's very easy to program after 5 brain surgeries like I have....

Comment: That'll be the `[html]` tag nitwits who know nothing about Facelets. Just ignore them. As to your concrete problem, that should work just fine. At least, I can't reproduce your problem here with Mojarra 2.1.7. What do you see in generated HTML output? The `å` should be URL-encoded as `%E5`, so the generated `<a>` element should end up pointing to the URL of `/Bughaugane-Hyttetomt-salg-og-Filefjell-omr%E5de-Nyheiter.xhtml`.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version exactly are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Tomcat, you need to tell it to interpret URLs using UTF-8. Open `/conf/server.xml`, locate the `<Connector>` element which is been used by your webapp and add the `URIEncoding` attribute with value of `UTF-8`.

```xml
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

This way you don't need to manually change the URLs with special characters.

Comment: Hi BalusC. This did not work in my latest deployment, but did prior to this. It works in development Tomcat 7.0.27, but fails on production, yet I included the aforementioned attribute. any clues as to why? As an example, `<img jsfc="h:graphicImage"
                 src="/hyttefelt-på-toppen-av-filefjell-mellom-østlandet-og-vestlandet-på-filefjell-buhaugane-hyttefelt-norge.png"
                 url="/hyttefelt-på-toppen-av-filefjell-mellom-østlandet-og-vestlandet-på-filefjell-buhaugane-hyttefelt-norge.png"
                 alt="#{global.headerAltImage1}"/>`

Comment: This results in unrendered source of `<img src="/hyttefelt-p%C3%A5-toppen-av-filefjell-mellom-%C3%B8stlandet-og-vestlandet-p%C3%A5-filefjell-buhaugane-hyttefelt-norge.png" alt="Buhaugane hyttefelt på toppen av Filefjell"/>`

Answer (score 0):

As BalusC kindly commented. Url encoding should fix this.
[here are codes I needed](http://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/)

Comment: I didn't mean that. Facelets should already automatically do that. You shouldn't need to manually URL-encode the character in the `faces-config.xml` file. I was just asking what exactly you're seeing in the generated HTML output, so that we can spot the possible cause. One of the possible causes is that  you've saved the `faces-config.xml` file itself using the wrong encoding.

Comment: @BalusC UTF-8 is my current encoding. Should I change?

Comment: No, UTF-8 is fine and is what you should be using. Facelets uses UTF-8 by default already. But you have still not answered what you're seeing in the generated HTML output. Open the page containing the link in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. What characters exactly do you see in `href` attribute instead of `å`? It should be `%E5`.

Comment: @BalusC It depends I fixed both issues by altering the file names, but I have your fix to help me should I experience again. There was no output. Just a url that looked nothing like the one configured in the configuration file. In the second case the `<h:graphicImage>` was no longer rendering

Comment: Which URL exactly was that? Was it `RES_NOT_FOUND` or something? That would then in turn indidate that Java file system encoding is not set to UTF-8.

Comment: I can't remember, other than some numerics replacing the å in the url.

Comment: Then I can't answer your question. Right now you've just a workaround, not a solution. That wasn't my intent.

Comment: @BalusC I removed the fix with the image and the image is no longer rendered (only the alt message). Code inspection reveals this: `<img src="Utsikt-mot-Buhaugane-Hyttetomter-til-salg-p%C3%A5-Filefjell.png" alt="Bilete er ikkje funne. (Trykke på F5)" title="Utsikt mot Buhaugane Hyttefelt">

            <ul id="listA">
                <li>I Buhaugane hyttefelt på Filefjell i Lærdal kommune vert 40 hyttetomter no lagt ut for sal. Feltet vil ferdig utbygd romme inntil 100 hytter.</li>`

Comment: @BalusC This works though: `<img jsfc="h:graphicImage"
                     src="Utsikt-mot-Buhaugane-Hyttetomter-til-salg-på-Filefjell.png"
                     url="Utsikt-mot-Buhaugane-Hyttetomter-til-salg-p%E5-Filefjell.png"
                     title="#{index.img1Title}"
                     alt="#{global.alt}"/>`

Comment: Okay, I see. How about the link?

Comment: @BalusC The å is in the url, but 404 and am using myFaces 2.1.6

Comment: Oh, it is thus not encoded at all? I will try to reproduce this with MyFaces 2.1.6. I can at least not reproduce it with Mojarra 2.1.7.

Comment: @Balusc my `<welcome-file>` in web .xml also make use of a file with the `å` Something very interesting happens. The page is rendered when launching the application in IDEA. The welcome file is also referenced via DHTML in a banner `div` which together with a home link produce `404` page in Tomcat 7.0.27